# Rails Controller Interprets "null" as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have API (JSON) calls coming in that are passing the string `"null"`, not the object `null`, but both are getting interpreted as `nil`.  The second one, of course, SHOULD be interpreted that way, but `"null"` should be handled the same as any other string.

Is there a simple way of doing this?  JSON.parse does it the right way, it's only when it's being interpreted through ActionParameters that it's wrong.

request.raw_post:
`{"task":{"description":"null"}}`

params:
`<ActionController::Parameters {"task"=><ActionController::Parameters {"description"=>nil} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"example_controller", "action"=>"example_action", "id"=>"1234"} permitted: false>`

JSON.parse:
`{"task"=>{"description"=>"null"}}`

For now, for lack of a better option, in my API parent controller, if the request content type is application/json, I am parsing the raw post with JSON parse, then overwriting the value in the params method.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? Is it the most up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, it's the latest version.